# How to make Selenium read content?

Tags: c#, selenium

Can we make Selenium read certain data from a web page??

For Example: I am visiting a web page and it has some content formatted in a table like:

```
App Name    Wiki
Price       250.00
App Number  Igk4745
```

The main problem is that all of these fields have the same ID, NAME, TAG NAME etc. How can I make selenium identify these attributes differently and read those fields? (Atleast store the values in a variable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using below logic you can get all the webelements with same locator.

```
List<WebElement> element=driver.FindElements(By.Id("id"));
```

After getting List of webelements iterate through list and get the content (inner html) of those elements.

```
foreach (WebElement ele in element)
{
   Console.WriteLine(ele.Text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks..But I dont want to display that value. I just want to store into some variable.Could you please edit your answer based on that?

Comment: You'd just need to create a new variable that equals `ele.Text` instead of printing it out.